# Django should I use an optional related field or get_or_create?

Tags: django, models

I have the a `ForeignKey` field on the `User` model.

```
company = models.ForeignKey('crm.Company')
```

So every user needs to have a company.

The problem is the `create_super_user` method does not have a `company` at the start of a project and I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'users_user.company_id' in 'field list'")
```

So would it be best to just create a default `Company` and assign it with `get_or_create` like:

```
def create_superuser(self, email, password, **kwargs):
    company, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
        name='Default Company',
    )
    kwargs.setdefault('company', company)
    kwargs.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    kwargs.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    kwargs.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if kwargs.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have staff=True')
    if kwargs.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True')
    return self.create_user(email, password, **kwargs)
```

The problem may arise when I create a new superuser from command line and the `Default company` has changed. Now a new `Default Company` will be created.

On the other hand I can make the `company` field optional with `null=True` but now that breaks the system rules that each user is associated to a company.

How else can I ensure a company has been created already?

Answer (score 2):

You can add `BooleanField` to the company model:

```
is_default = BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now in `create_superuser` you can search company by this field. You can use `defaults` argument of `get_or_create` to set new company name in case of default company does not exists:

```
company, created = Company.objects.get_or_create(
    is_default=True, 
    defaults={'name': 'Default Company'}
)
```